# How to solve this exercise?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, time-series

This exercise is from 
**Hadley Wickham auth. ggplot2 Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis**

> The final plot shows a lot of short-term noise in the overall trend.
>   How could you smooth this further to focus on long-term changes?

The final plot is here.

```
library(tidyverse)
deseas <- function(x, month) {
  resid(lm(x ~ factor(month), na.action = na.exclude))
}
txhousing <- txhousing %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(rel_sales = deseas(log(sales), month))
ggplot(txhousing, aes(date, rel_sales)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = city), alpha = 1/5) +
  geom_line(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", colour = "red")
```

[image]

This code removes the seasonal effects.

A consistent increase from 2000–2007, a
drop until 2010 (with quite some noise), and then a gradual rebound.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is a broad question - there are multiple smoothening algorithms available. Consider focusing the question a bit.

Comment: May I ask you show a one algorithms..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just interested in a smooth line in the plot or are you looking for smoothed values?

If you're just after plotting, you could use the `geom_smooth` function:

```
ggplot(txhousing, aes(date, rel_sales)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = city), alpha = 1/5) +
  geom_smooth(stat = "smooth", colour = "red", method="auto")
```

Or call it with a defined formula with the `splines` package. This allows you to adjust the degrees of freedom and the degree of the piecewise polynomial.

```
ggplot(txhousing, aes(date, rel_sales)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = city), alpha = 1/5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = 15, degree = 3), se = FALSE)
```

Comment: I don'y know why  `df = 15` and `degree = 3` in `splines::bs`?  Is high order polynmial  incorrect?

Comment: That looked best to me and was also just meant as illustration. I dont think its incorrect, it depends on what smoothing effect you want. You could also try `df = 5, degree = 1` if you want a more linear smoothing effect.